# Sybase 15.7 Merge - handling extraneous rows in destination table

Tags: merge, sybase

I've cobbled together a merge command that updates matching rows and inserts rows that are missing in the destination table.  However, I'm at a loss as to how to remove rows in the destination table that are not in the source table.  I've been unable to find that spelled out in any documentation.  Any suggestions or applicable references very much appreciated!

Comment: I noticed that sql server offers a "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET" clause, but thus far I haven't found an equivalent for Sybase.

Answer (score 0):

In ASE, you can only do WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE, so delete rows that *do* exist in both the source and the destination. 
For what you describe, you need to do something like 'DELETE t1 where  not in (SELECT pk from t2)'